# How to protect my code from "Index out of range" errors

Tags: python, arraylist

I've been trying to build a simple calendar as coding exercise in my free time. However, I can't seem  to be able to sort out this problem:

How do I return to item 0 in a list? My idea was to, whenever dayoftheweek is longer than the length of the list, it returns to days[0], but I can't seem to be able to get it to work.

```
days = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]
dayoftheweek = days[0]

userchoice = int(input("Please add a number to days: "))
dayoftheweek = days[userchoice]
```

If the user input `8`, I got a `Index out of range` error.

**How can I catch inputs out of the range of my `days` and default to `0`?**

Comment: Can you be a little more clear? What do you think `days[+userchoice]` does (and what do you want it to do)? All it ever does is give you the value `days[userchoice]` -- there is no "counter" that keeps track of and adds to some current value unless you make it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use modulo:

```
dayoftheweek = days[userchoice % len(days)]
```

Comment: maybe `days[userchoice % len(days)]` ?

Comment: Yes, but knowing that the number of days in a week is unlikely to ever change, this is one of the cases where hard-coding is okay in my opinion. But then again, I've updated my answer as it does make for a better code.